# Lotus Notes 8.5 hyperlinks in emails are not opening as expected

Tags: email, lotus-notes, hyperlink

I have a user with Lotus Notes 8.5.1 who is having issues opening hyperlinks.

When you click on a link from an email, the line under the link text just flashes.

I updated her to fix pack 8.5.2 and I'm still seeing the same thing. I also updated her to Internet Explorer 8.

Does anyone know what the fix for this would be? done a complete uninstall and reinstall, all to no avail.

Comment: Check what the Internet Browser setting is in the Location doc.  If it's not a valid browser, then the link won't open.  Did it ever work on that system before?

Comment: Hmm... Where would this location doc file be? It worked at one point, about a year ago. But ever since then, it hasn't and I am the one put in charge of fixing it... :/

Comment: It's in the user's names.nsf.  Open names.nsf (File->Application->Open), and in the left panel choose "Advanced->Locations".  There'll probably be only one location listed.  Whichever one is selected is the current one, so open that to edit, click on the "Internet Browser" tab, and see which browser is listed.

Comment: The web browser is set by our Notes policy, so nothing can be changed in here...

Comment: Can you at least check what it's set to?  Maybe the web browser of choice isn't where Notes thinks it should be.  Just a thought...

Comment: What other troubleshooting, if any, has been attempted already?  Have you tried reconfiguring their notes.ini (wipe everything after the directory lines), delete cache.ndk and bookmark.nsf, delete perweb.nsf which is the component that downloads the web content.

Comment: Had you tried resetting IE as the default browser? Which OS are you running?

Comment: Eric, it is set to IE8! I know this, becuase I installed IE8 as a possible fix. Which it is the default browser.
Zach, I have reconfigured the notes.ini, deleted the cache.ndk. I did not delete perweb.nsf or bookmark.nsf, this is possible that it would have worked.
Thank you all for your help and quick responses! I needed to get this fixed asap, so my work around was to change the name.id file to name.old, log in with my account, test to see if lotus notes works correctly with the users id file. I was able to click on hyper links within the users e-mail. This led me to believe that this is..

Comment: a profile dependent issue. I then backed up all data to the server, deleted the user profile, had her log back in, recreating the users profile, download all data back to the user profile and test Notes again to see if it worked. Issue resolved!

Comment: We have a few more users that are now reporting the same issue. We'll try what you had reccomended and hopefully this resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this issue in the past, where we force IE upon our clients.  Someone had installed a 3rd party browser, set it to default, and then IE was set back by the policy.  Client could not open link.  I was able to resolve by reverting to an earlier install of IE, and reinstalling IE8.  When IE was reinstalled, Notes then realized it was there, and used it for links.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue in IBM Notes 9 Social, the locations section has changed.

File->Locations->Manage Locations

Then under each of the locations, select your current location and the Click "Edit", click on the Internet Browser tab, and set your default browser there.

Hope this helps someone

Comment: I do not have Internet Browser tab there. (I am using Release 9.0.1FP5 SHF164)

Answer (score 0):

open the reg.edit, then:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\mailto

From the Edit menu, select New, and then click String Value.
Type 'URL Protocol' as the name of the new String Value
Exit the Registry Editor

that solves the bug